# Aws lambda that access RDS mysql gets timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services

Im tryng to query my RDS table with a simple select, its working fine when i run the Api gateway locally with sam local, but when i try to access on the cloud i get a time out error

```
{ Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:163:17)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Handshake.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Handshake._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:124:8)
    at Timer._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Timer.js:32:23)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at Promise (/var/task/app/services/repositoryService.js:73:12)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports.selectFavoritePokemons (/var/task/app/services/repositoryService.js:61:12)
    at module.exports.getAllFavoritePokemon (/var/task/app/requests/pokemon.js:40:30)
  code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
  fatal: true,
  timeout: 10000 }
2019-02-06T19:08:52.866Z    f24ef50f-be42-4753-8472-7a6648d7edd6    TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at pool.getConnection (/var/task/app/services/repositoryService.js:75:20)
    at Handshake.onConnect (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:58:9)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at Handshake._callback (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:468:16)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at /var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:396:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:395:13
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
END RequestId: f24ef50f-be42-4753-8472-7a6648d7edd6
```

the function

```
module.exports.selectFavoritePokemons = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      var env = new Enviroment();
      var pool = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 1000,
        connectTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
        acquireTimeout   : 60 * 60 * 1000,
        timeout         : 60 * 60 * 1000,
        host: env.props.db.host,
        user: env.props.db.user,
        password: env.props.db.password,
        database: env.props.db.database,
        port: 3306
        });


      var query =   `SELECT * FROM FavoritePokemon`;
      pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
          console.log(err)
        connection.query(query,  (error, results, fields) => {
          if (error) {
          connection.release();
          return reject(error)
          } ;
          let obj = [];
          console.log(results)
          results.forEach(row =>{
            obj.push({name: row.Name,type: row.Type,imageURL: row.ImageURL})
          });
          console.log(obj)
          resolve(obj);
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

Tried increasing the timeout, but had no luck. Not sure whats causing this,
any ideas?

Comment: Check if your Lambda has an appropriate role to access RDS mysql.

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons why your lambda might be getting timed out, usually related to security settings (but not limited to).

I would start with

1. check whether the VPC access is enabled for lambda, if your lambda is not running in a VPC then you will not be able to access your private RDS
2. check the security groups if you are allowing the connection between lambda and RDS, this connection may not be allowed in your SG which would cause the mentioned timeout
3. check whether lambda has proper IAM policies attached to its role so that it has required permissions to communicate with RDS

Comment: #3 would not cause a timeout.  IAM permissions would only be relevant if the db is using IAM auth, and the result would be "access denied."  The other two are lilely candidates.